# which the best way to get some data in text below

Tags: python, python-2.7

Without modules xml or lxml,
with module re
or maybe another way,
how best to get the data between the quotes: https://10.107.11.77:52311/api/computer/1624350712

my option with re:
found = re.findall(r'<Computer Resource=\s*"([^"]*)"', r.text)

Text:

```xml
<Computer Resource="https://10.107.11.77:52311/api/computer/1624350712">
<LastReportTime>Thu, 13 May 2021 22:59:43 +0000</LastReportTime>
<ID>1624350712</ID>
</Computer>
<Computer Resource="https://10.107.11.77:52311/api/computer/1626165598">
<LastReportTime>Wed, 02 Jun 2021 07:12:40 +0000</LastReportTime>
<ID>1626165598</ID>
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! Is there any reason why you cannot use lxml? Please post your code and the output you are getting so that we can see what you have attempted.

Comment: I can only work with modules that are allowed in the organization. I don't have access to get lxml. 
output: [https://10.107.11.77:52311/api/computer/1624350712,https://10.107.11.77:52311/api/computer/1626165598]

Comment: If you want to find a solution through regex, I would suggest using the following website where you can past your text and try multiple regex searches. https://regexr.com/

Answer (score 0):

my option with re: found = re.findall(r'<Computer Resource=\s*"([^"]*)"', r.text)